# How to return the text file data through an API endpoint in JSON format using Dataflow and SpringBoot framework?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I have an input.txt file as below:

```
"John"
"Sena"
"01/01/1976"
"Surrey"
```

I would like to have an endpoint which will return the data in the below format:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Sena",
  "dateOfBirth": "01/01/1976",
  "placeOfBirth": "Surrey"
}
```

I want to use GCP Dataflow to process the text file and Spring Boot framework to have the final endpoint.

Right now I am able to read the input.txt file through the dataflow job. Next I want to return the data through an endpoint.

How should I proceed? Please can someone assist me.

Comment: The output of a `PCollection` is usually sent to a Beam storage Connector. You will need to write a post transform function to read the PCollection and post to an endpoint. I recommend storing the transformed data in Cloud Storage and using to Pub/Sub to notify your endpoint to read the data instead of pushing to an API endpoint. Where possible make data persistent and asynchronous. This helps with debugging and analyzing errors.

Answer (score 0):

A sample code could be as given below, if input file is comma separated file :-

```
class Transaction(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
    -->>***Conversion of data to JSON based on element-number*** <<---
    return [{JSON-Data}]

    data_loading = (
        p1
        |'Read from File' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input,skip_header_lines=0)
        |'Splitting of Fields' >> beam.Map(lambda record: record.split(','))
        |'Concerting to JSON' >> beam.ParDo(Transaction())
        |'Pushing on endpoint' >> ...... end point ...
    )
```